# How can I make `enscript` block till the printer finishes its job?

Tags: bash, printing, signals, enscript, wait

The following command will create a pdf file under `~/PDF/`:

```
enscript -B -P PDF  bloom.c
```

I want to move the output pdf file here

```
mv "`ls -dtr1 ~/PDF/* | tail -1`" .
```

But I can't run the `mv` command immedately follow the `enscript` command, because `enscript` sends the input file to the printer PDF, and returns immediately before the printer finishes creating a pdf file.

A very bad solution is to insert the following command between the two commands

```
sleep 5
```

It is bad because I don't know how long I shall wait.

Note that I know there is other better way to do the same thing without having to run the `mv` command after `enscript`, but I just wonder if there is any way to make `enscript` block till the printer finishes its job? I remember having similar thoughts for other commands besides`enscript`.
I am assuming that `enscript` doesn't provide such an option, so would be interested in whether bash or other program can make that happen. Signal handling might be a solution, but I don't know which signal to catch.

Comment: Hi @Tim, i would suggest that you try `wait ` instead of `sleep` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296863/difference-between-wait-and-sleep

Comment: Does `lpstat -p PDF` show something different if you run it while the printer is generating the output file vs. after it finishes generating the file? If so, it may be possible to write a shell script to do what you need.

Comment: @Goro  `enscript -B -P PDF code/bloom.c & wait $!` will not work, because the job of `enscript` returns immediately.

Comment: @Tim. I would suggest that you change your approach. Instead of `sleep`  let the script sense when the PDF file is really exist in the path then move it. Use `if then statement`

Comment: enscript [just runs the lpr command](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=enscript.git;a=blob;f=src/prt_lpr.c;hb=HEAD), along with any options that you pass to it. I don't know offhand how to make cups not spool, that is, how to make the `lpr` command only exit after the printer driver has run to completion. If you don't get an answer here, you might consider asking the more general question about the cups `lpr` command.

Answer (score 1):

As this is too large to put into a comment, have you tried checking whether any files in the `~/PDF` directory are still open [while they're begin spooled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471116/what-does-spool-mean-for-printing/471125#471125) by using `lsof` (LiSt Open Files)?

Add this code snippet after your `enscript -B -P PDF  bloom.c`:

```
# Go into endless loop and break when all files in */PDF/* are closed.
while :
do
    if ! [[ `lsof | grep /PDF/` ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

and before the

```
mv "`ls -dtr1 ~/PDF/* | tail -1`"
```

This way you lose only 1 second...

For more info:

- `lsof` will list all currently open files
- the obligatory `man lsof` will give you even more details.

**;-)**